# Circular dead spots on Boxwood shrub - identification and treatment

Tags: plant-health, diseases, plant-recommendations, shrubs

I am trying to figure out why my shrubs are showing dead spots and, in some cases, complete sides of the shrubs are dying off.

Can anyone help me:

1. Identify what this shrub is
2. Why they are all showing signs of disease?
3. How to treat this issue.

(I think the plant might be a Green Mountain Boxwood Broadleaf Evergreen Shrub)

NOTE: I will update the title of this question once the plant has been identified to help others with future searches.

[image: Diseased shrub with demise]

### Updates for Questions

**Location**:
Alabama, USA (Southeast)

### [image: Close-up of affected area]

[image: Medium view of affected shrub]

Comment: Can you add a close up and the location of the plants?

Comment: @kevinskio Updated question and added more photos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like [Box Blight](https://www.rhs.org.uk/disease/box-blight).

This is rampant this year where I live in Southern England.  Unfortunately, everyone I know who has attempted a cure has failed.  The only remedy appears to be to burn the shrub and plant something else.

The loss of Box around here is devastating.

Comment: I think you're correct in your assessment. After doing more research I think this is what I have. We have a fungus called Southern Blight and I believe this to be the cause of the demise.